# Spring MVC form submit: view to controller pass not put form attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a  portlet that is able to display form and then allow to pass to the controller in an object what was set by the user. 
And it works well. Just I want that the app is able to set an additional attribute from the jsp but not coming from the input of forms.

**The model**

```
public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String attributeSetStatically;

    // Setters and getters

    public void setAttributeSetStatically(String attributeFromJsp)
    {
        System.out.println("Call setAttributeSetStatically  "+attributeFromJsp);
        this.attributeSetStatically=attributeFromJsp;
    }
}
```

**The controller**

```
@Controller(value = "MyFirstSpringMVCPortlet")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyFirstSpringMVCPortlet {

    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("person", new Person());
        modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return modelAndView; 
    }


    @ActionMapping(value = "handleSubmitPerson")
    public void submitPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person,ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,Model model) {
            System.out.println("FirstName= "+person.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("MiddleName= "+person.getMiddleName());
            System.out.println("attributeSetStatically= "+person.getAttributeSetStatically());
    }

}
```

**view(welcome.jsp)**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<h1>${msg}</h1>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL var="submitFormURL" name="handleSubmitPerson"/>
<form:form name="person" method="post" modelAttribute="person" action="<%=submitFormURL.toString() %>">
${person.setAttributeSetStatically('attributeSetStatically of person')}
<br/>
    <table style="margin-left:80px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName"></form:input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="middleName">Middle Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="middleName"></form:input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

The output that I got as a result in the console is:

```
FirstName= Kallel
MiddleName= Omar
attributeSetStatically= null
Call setAttributeSetStatically  attributeSetStatically of person
```

So this ${person.setAttributeSetStatically('attributeSetStatically of person')} is called after the submit. Why? Is there a solution to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attributeSetStatically` can be set in hidden input inside of the form:

```
<form:input type="hidden" name="attributeSetStatically" value="attributeSetStatically of person">
```

Comment: just a remark here after your last update to form:input you have also to change name to path ;-)